# Pygame Collision not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

For my computing project I need to make some sort of app or game. I decided I would make space invaders. I have managed to get the basics working, the sprites would spawn I could move the player, the enemies fell from the top of the screen and the background and music worked properly, but the collision is not working properly. When the corners touch or the midpoint between two corners touch then it works fine, the program closes. But if the corners/midpoints don't touch then the sprites pass right through each other. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code :

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WHITE  = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK  = (  0,   0,   0)
RED    = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN  = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE   = (  0,   0, 255)
ORANGE = (255, 255,   0)
YELLOW = (  0, 255, 255)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 720
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 720

FPS = 60

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images\\user1.gif").convert()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed_x = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speed_x = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speed_x = -7
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speed_x = 7
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        if self.rect.right > DISPLAY_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = DISPLAY_WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0


class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images\\enemy1.gif").convert()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, DISPLAY_WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(3, 11)

    def update(self):
            self.rect.y +=self.speedy
            if self.rect.top > DISPLAY_HEIGHT + 10:
                self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, DISPLAY_WIDTH - self.rect.width)
                self.rect.y = random.randrange(-100, -40)
                self.speedy = random.randrange(3, 11)

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

# empty

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# - init -

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
display_rect = display.get_rect()

# - objects -

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player()
player.rect.center = ((DISPLAY_WIDTH / 2), DISPLAY_HEIGHT/1.2)

all_sprites.add(player)
for z in range(8):
    mob = Mob()
    mobs.add(mob)
    all_sprites.add(mob)
background = pygame.image.load("images\\background.jpg")
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))

# - other -

pygame.mixer.music.load("audio\\soundtrack.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.4)

# - mainloop -

crashed = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not crashed:

    # - events -
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        print(event)


# - checks for a hit -
    col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(mob, player)
    if col:
            sys.exit()
# - updates (without draws) -

    all_sprites.update()

# - draws (without updates) -

    display.blit(background, (0, 0))

    all_sprites.draw(display)

    pygame.display.update()

# - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)

# - end -
pygame.quit()
```

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `pygame.sprite.collide_rect` is not intended for direct use. It's intended to be passed into the 'main' collide functions

1. `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()`
2. `pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`
3. `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()`

In your case you want [pygame.sprite.spritecollideany](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany):

```
col = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, mobs)
if col:
    sys.exit()
```

This function will return one in `mobs` that collided with `player`.